# I am trying to pass this array but with numbers only into function

Tags: perl

I am writing a small automation script for a workflow for my job. I need to pass a set of numbers as inputs (which are beginning input from a JSON file) into my Perl function. Here is my code:

```
my $idFile='GNOC_IDS.json';
my $idJSON;
{
    local $/;
    open my $fh, '<', $idFile or die $!;
    $idJSON = <$fh>;
    close $fh;
}
my $id_array = decode_json $idJSON;
my @decodedIDS = Dumper(\$id_array);
foreach my $ids(@decodedIDS){
    print $ids;
    my $results= $client->get_entities(
            entity_id=>$ids

            );
    print Dumper(\$results);
}
```

However, my problem is that the `$ids` have the following format:

```
[       {
          'MISC' => '1743'
        },
        {
          'MISC' => '1743'
        },
        {
          'MISC' => '1733'
        },
        {
          'MISC' => '2736'
        },
        {
          'MISC' => '1763'
        },
        {
          'MISC' => '3133'
        },
        {
          'MISC' => '1743'
        },
        {
          'MISC' => '1733'
        },
        {
          'MISC' => '2802'
        },
        {
          'MISC' => '1699'
        },
        {
          'MISC' => '2736'
        },
        {
          'MISC' => '2600'
        }
]
```

I want to feed just the numbers (e.g., 1699, 2735, etc.) into the `get_entities` function because right now its giving me an "input must be integer only error".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `$id_array` is as follows, you can use [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) instead of `Dumper` to access just the numbers:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $id_array = [
        {
          'MISC' => '1743'
        },
        {
          'MISC' => '1743'
        },
        {
          'MISC' => '1733'
        },
        {
          'MISC' => '2736'
        },
        {
          'MISC' => '1763'
        },
        {
          'MISC' => '3133'
        },
];

my @decodedIDS = map { $_->{MISC} } @{ $id_array };
print Dumper(\@decodedIDS);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '1743',
          '1743',
          '1733',
          '2736',
          '1763',
          '3133'
        ];
```

Answer (score -1):

There's two ways to do this, flatten before you loop over it or reference each item's data in the loop.

Flatten:

```
…
foreach my $ids (map {$_->{'MISC'}} @decodedIDS){ …
…
```

Or refer to contents:

```
…
foreach my $ids (@decodedIDS) {
    print $ids->{'MISC'};
…
```